# Difference of variable initialization in C++

Tags: c++

Is there any difference between these 2 ways of storing an integer?

```
int X = 100;
```

and

```
int *pX = new int(100);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Is there any difference between these 2 ways of storing an integer?"*

Yes, there is a significant difference.

> ```
>  int X = 100;
> ```

Initializes a variable `X` on the stack with the value `100`, while

> ```
> int *pX = new int(100);
> ```

allocates memory for an `int` on the heap, kept in pointer `pX`, and initializes the value to `100`.

For the latter you should notice, that it's necessary to deallocate that heap memory, when it's no longer needed:

```
 delete pX;
```

Comment: Just like what I expected.  Thanks for confirming it.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is creating a variable on the stack while the second one is creating a variable on the heap and creating a pointer to point at it.